# В Proxmox 7.2-3 виртуальные машины не доступны в локальной сети

Tags: сеть, proxmox

Судя по информации в интернете, Проксмокс по умолчанию выводит все виртуальные машины в физическую локальную сеть, в которой работает сам хост.

У меня настройки по умолчанию, виртуальные машины и сам проксмокс фактически нетронутые. Виртуальные машины могут пинговать всю локальную сеть и ходить в интернет, причем при получении пингов и запросов в локалке отображается корректный адрес виртуальной машины (то есть виртуалки не прячутся за NAT'ом хоста или что-то в этом роде). Однако, сами виртуальные машины недоступны из локальной сети: не идут пинги и что-либо еще. В попытках решить проблему пробовал отключать фаерволы на гостевых операционных системах, но результата это не дало - виртуалки по прежнему не пингуются.

Сетевой конфиг хоста:

```
root@host:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp1s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100/24
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    bridge-ports enp1s0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
```

К виртуалкам цепляется только `vmbr0`.

В какую сторону смотреть, как получить доступ к виртуальным машинам в локальной сети?

Answer (score 0):

Если Proxmox запущен поверх другого гипервизора, например ESXi, то надо включить promiscuous mode в настройках виртуального свича. Выбираете нужный vSwitch и в настройках Security включаете Accept в Promiscuous mode.